# How to upload a DB file to the app(apk) installed on the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, sqlite, apk

I want to upload an existing DB file, an SQLite Database, to my installed APK on my emulator. I tried to see if the APK file contains an asset file, but it doesn't. So, I decided to use console command to push the DB file. I can store my DB file to the SD card in the Emulator

I am not sure how this process works. Can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to do after moving DB file to emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

**Android Studio > Device File Explorer:**

[image]

Copy your sqlite db and go to `/data/data/your_app_packagename/databases/` , right click then paste it there.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the info. However, I cannot find the databases folder somehow. All I see is cache, chache code, and lib folders.

Answer (score 1):

Most often if you have a database you create the assets folder in `src/main` folder and if using `SQLiteAssetHelper` create databases folder in the assets folder.

Next is to copy the database file into the assets folder or `assets/databases` folder if using `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

With the App you use a class that extends `SQLiteAssetHelper` (after add dependency `implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'`) with 2nd parameter to constructor the database name (the file name including extension). SQLiteAssetHelper will copy the database from the asset to the normal location (data/data/the_package/databases/databasename).

Another way is to do the copy yourself if the database does not exist, most often this would be using a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Another way for emulator only is to use Device Explorer to first create the databases folder in data/data/packagename and then copy the database file into the databases folder. This way not good as it only works for emulator or if you have access to `data/data/packagename`.

Copy from assets folder is the right way as database file is part of the APK and working on the emulator and other devices.

*above packagename is the name of the package, not the word packagename*

## How to do both ways from the assets folder.

Create the project (empty was used)

The assets folder is created and databases folder is created in the assets folder and 1 database file is copied into assets/databases

[image]

Other database file copied to assets folder

[image]

Module Build Gradle has added line

```
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
```

First class uses SQLiteAssetHelper that is

```
public class DBAssetHelper1 extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    static String DATABASE_NAME = "databasefile1";

    public DBAssetHelper1(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
}
```

Another class use SQLiteOpenhelper that is longer coz copy is done by it

```
public class DBAssetHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static String DATABASE_NAME = "databasefile2";

    public DBAssetHelper2(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        String databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        if (!doesDatabaseExist(databasePath)) {
            copyDatabaseFromAssets(context,databasePath,DATABASE_NAME);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private boolean doesDatabaseExist(String databasepath) {
        if (new File(databasepath).exists()) return true;
        if (new File(databasepath).getParentFile().exists()) return false;
        new File(databasepath).getParentFile().mkdirs();
        return false;
    }

    private void copyDatabaseFromAssets(Context context, String databasepath, String assetfilename) {
        int bSize = 4096, bytes = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bSize];
        try {
            InputStream asset = context.getAssets().open(assetfilename);
            FileOutputStream database = new FileOutputStream(new File(databasepath));
            while((bytes = asset.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                database.write(buffer,0,bytes);
            }
            database.flush();
            database.close();
            asset.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error copy Asset File " + assetfilename + " to " + databasepath);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing both for showing MainActivity shows databases from sqlite_master

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBAssetHelper1 dbAssetHelper1;
    DBAssetHelper2 dbAssetHelper2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbAssetHelper1 = new DBAssetHelper1(this);
        Cursor cursor1 = dbAssetHelper1.getReadableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor1);

        dbAssetHelper2 = new DBAssetHelper2(this);
        Cursor cursor2 = dbAssetHelper2.getReadableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor2);
        cursor1.close();
        cursor2.close();
    }
}
```

This says to log

> ```
> W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
> W/SQLiteAssetHelper: database copy complete
> I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database databasefile1
> I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@a4595f9
> I/System.out: 0 {
> I/System.out:    type=table
> I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
> I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
> I/System.out:    rootpage=3
> I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
> I/System.out: }
> I/System.out: 1 {
> I/System.out:    type=table
> I/System.out:    name=mytable
> I/System.out:    tbl_name=mytable
> I/System.out:    rootpage=4
> I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`id` INTEGER, `value` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
> I/System.out: }
> I/System.out: <<<<<
> I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@7065b4a
> I/System.out: 0 {
> I/System.out:    type=table
> I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
> I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
> I/System.out:    rootpage=3
> I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
> I/System.out: }
> I/System.out: 1 {
> I/System.out:    type=table
> I/System.out:    name=mytable
> I/System.out:    tbl_name=mytable
> I/System.out:    rootpage=4
> I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`id` INTEGER, `value` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
> I/System.out: }
> I/System.out: <<<<<
> ```